# Python: ImportError: No module named os

Tags: python, django, mod-wsgi

**error_log**

```
...
[Fri Sep 07 16:30:14 2012] [error] import os
[Fri Sep 07 16:30:14 2012] [error] ImportError: No module named os
```

**-shell-**

```
[root@lts5srv1 home]# ldd /root/epd-5.1.0/bin/python
    libpython2.5.so.1.0 => /root/epd-5.1.0/lib/libpython2.5.so.1.0 (0x00002b0829205000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x0000003da0600000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x0000003d9fe00000)
    libutil.so.1 => /lib64/libutil.so.1 (0x0000003dadc00000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x0000003da0200000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x0000003d9fa00000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003d9f600000)
```

Anybody know how to solve this error? it's the only error that i get when i try to run a python script or a django.wsgi script in a redhat system, after that i'm going to upload my web-app in a university server... and i've already configuret the VirtualHost. So that was the only problem, can anybody help please? Thank You.

Comment: your python install is messed up ...

Comment: yes! In fact importing os from the command line.. i don't get any error.. $ python, >>> import os, >>> os, >>> <module 'os' from '/root/epd-5.1.0/lib/python2.5/os.pyc'>..

Comment: Are you sure that mod_wsgi and the REPL are using the same Python install?

Comment: Run `ldd` against the module.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the help. I've solved the problem installing python2.6 and re-installing every needed module with python2.6, so i've stopped using the default installed python..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution for that problem (in redhat system), this is a solution in relation with Django framework..

I've installed Python 2.6 (so i don't use anymore the default installed python), and reinstalled Django using the new version of Python and some other modules that were required like: (**easy_isntall**, **MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.6-linux-x86_64**, **setuptools**, **mod_wsgi-2.5**) so after install all these modules should compare in the site-packages directory of Python 2.6: "**/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages**".

```
[root@lts5srv1 Python-2.6.8]# ./configure --enable-shared --prefix=/usr/local
[root@lts5srv1 Python-2.6.8]# make
[root@lts5srv1 Python-2.6.8]# make install
```

Configure mod_wsgi to link with Python 2.6 shared libs

```
[root@lts5srv1 /]# cd /usr/local/lib/python2.6/config/
[root@lts5srv1 config]# ln -s ../../libpython2.6.so .

[root@lts5srv1 mod_wsgi-2.5]# ./configure --with-python=/usr/local/bin/python2.6
[root@lts5srv1 mod_wsgi-2.5]# make 
[root@lts5srv1 mod_wsgi-2.5]# make install
```

Then setting the environment variables:

```
[root@lts5srv1 Python-2.6.8]# export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.6
[root@lts5srv1 Python-2.6.8]# export LD_RUN_PATH=/usr/lib64/httpd/modules
```

Editing **~/.bashrc** and adding some lines to keep the changes permanent:

```
[root@lts5srv1 ~]# vi ~/.bashrc

# .bashrc

# User specific aliases and functions

PATH=/root/epd-5.1.0/lib/python2.5:/root/epd-5.1.0/bin:${PATH}
PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.6
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.6
LD_RUN_PATH=/usr/lib64/httpd/modules

alias rm='rm -i'
alias cp='cp -i'
alias mv='mv -i'

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
fi
```

Django Install:

```
[root@lts5srv1 Django-1.4.1]# /usr/local/bin/python2.6 setup.py install
```

Then, checking if the modules are correctly integrated:

```
[root@lts5srv1 /]# ldd /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so
[root@lts5srv1 /]# ldd /usr/local/bin/python2.6
```