# Can't upgrade matplotlib in Ubuntu 12.04 with Canopy installed

Tags: python, matplotlib, upgrade, enthought, canopy

I'm trying to upgrade `matplotlib` in `Ubuntu 12.04`. When I run the command:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade matplotlib
```

I get this error:

```
Downloading/unpacking matplotlib
  Running setup.py egg_info for package matplotlib
    The required version of distribute (>=0.6.28) is not available,
    and can't be installed while this script is running. Please
    install a more recent version first, using
    'easy_install -U distribute'.

    (Currently using distribute 0.6.24dev-r0 (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages))
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    The required version of distribute (>=0.6.28) is not available,

and can't be installed while this script is running. Please

install a more recent version first, using

'easy_install -U distribute'.

(Currently using distribute 0.6.24dev-r0 (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages))

----------------------------------------
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 2
Storing complete log in /home/gabriel/.pip/pip.log
```

So I run:

```
easy_install -U distribute
```

and I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/gabriel/Enthought/Canopy_32bit/User/bin/easy_install", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('distribute', 'console_scripts', 'easy_install')()
  File "/home/gabriel/Enthought/Canopy_32bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.9.8-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 378, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/home/gabriel/Enthought/Canopy_32bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.9.8-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2565, in load_entry_point
    raise ImportError("Entry point %r not found" % ((group,name),))
ImportError: Entry point ('console_scripts', 'easy_install') not found
```

So there's something not working with my `Canopy` install. I'm using `Spyder` right now so I could uninstall `Canopy` to see if that helps, but the commands `sudo apt-get remove enthought*` and `sudo apt-get remove canopy*` find nothing to remove.

What can I do to upgrade matplotlib?

---

### Add

I followed the instructions to remove `Canopy` from [here](https://support.enthought.com/entries/23580651-Uninstalling-Canopy) and now when I run `easy_install -U distribute` I get:

```
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
ImportError: No module named site
```

which I believe is related with me deleting the line `source ~/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/activate` from `~/.profile`. I tried running the following commands as sudo:

```
apt-get autoclean
apt-get clean
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get -f install
dpkg --configure -a
apt-get install --reinstall python
```

but that did not work. Any ideas on how to fix this?

---

### Add 2

I tried setting `PYTHONHOME` with the command:

```
export PYTHONHOME=/usr/lib/python2.7
```

and now `easy_install -U distribute` returns:

```
ImportError: No module named site
```

Same thing with:

```
export PYTHONHOME=/usr/local/lib/python2.7
```

So now off to chase that error.

---

### Add 3

Setting:

```
export PYTHONHOME=/usr/lib/python2.7/
```

and then running the command as `sudo`:

```
sudo easy_install -U distribute
```

did the trick. I could then run `sudo pip install --upgrade matplotlib`. I'll add this as an answer in a minute.

Comment: well.. you could just re-download it http://matplotlib.org/downloads.html and install it manually

Comment: remove the `source ....` in `.profile`, log out and log in again.  You need to re-set your environmental variables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After removing `Canopy` I run:

```
export PYTHONHOME=/usr/lib/python2.7/
sudo easy_install -U distribute
sudo pip install --upgrade matplotlib
```

I could upgrade `matplotlib` that way.

Comment: I did this and now I get `ImportError: No module named os` whenever I try to run `python` from the command line. What happened? Please help.

Comment: @alavin89 you are getting that error because somewhere in your code you have the line `import os` and your python installation is probably broken. Try here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12320143/python-importerror-no-module-named-os

Comment: Thank you @Gabriel, I figured it out, answer posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28534506/python-importerror-no-module-named-os?noredirect=1#comment45388102_28534506