# can not upgrade matplotlib to 1.3.1

Tags: matplotlib, ubuntu-12.04, upgrade

The comment sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib is installing 1.1.1rc version, not the latest version. I need the matplotlib 1.3.1 for hatch fill between curves. No upgradation command found that lead to success. Nothing helpful in the web, that successfully works. Please help. Ubuntu version 12.04.

Comment: Repositories don't have the newest versions. Use `sudo pip install matplotlib`

Comment: I understood nothing. Can you please give me a complete code/command that works fine?

Comment: The command you need to use is `sudo pip install matplotlib`. You might need to `sudo apt-get install pip` before. Please add more details to your question, if you found nothing, please tell us what you searched for!

Comment: okay currently i have matplotlib 1.1.1rc (installed) with python 2.7. I need the latest 1.3.1 version. or at least the git that corrects the bug regarding hatch fill_between curves. My ubuntu is 12.04 lts.

Comment: yesterday, i followed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18064159/cant-upgrade-matplotlib
After that python or ipython was not recognized in the terminal.

Comment: Sorry, forgot you need to use `sudo pip install --upgrade matplotlib` if you currently have installed it. Not absolutely sure if you have.

Comment: Can I remove my matplotlib, and install a fresh copy of version 1.3.1? Yesterday i used sudo pip install --upgrade matplotlib . but got errors. So i followed exactly the answer steps (only) of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18064159/cant-upgrade-matplotlib
after that python was not recognized. So what to do?

Comment: It depends on how you installed it. You could try `sudo apt-get remove python-matplotlib`, but I don't think that will have a real advantage. I use pip upgrade as described by me above several times on several Ubuntu boxes. Neither has is caused any error one one of them, nor can I see any reason why this would be so dangerous that it could break python

Comment: Running setup.py egg_info for package matplotlib
    The required version of distribute (>=0.6.28) is not available,
    and can't be installed while this script is running. Please
    install a more recent version first, using
    'easy_install -U distribute'.
I GOT THIS ERROR. I GOT IT YESTERDAY ALSO.

Comment: This error message is as clear as it will get. It even tells you the command to use. Is there any specific reason why you don't simply execute the command listed in the error message?

Comment: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/test-easy-install-7568.pth'
Now i got this error while tried to execute 'easy_install -U distribute'

Comment: You need to execute that as root, via `sudo`, unless you are inside a virtualenv (if you don't know that you are inside one, you are not inside one).

Comment: so the code will be, sudo easy_install -U distribute  ?

Comment: Yes, `sudo easy_install -U distribute `, is correct!

Comment: THANKS. IT WORKS FINE. ITS A PLEASURE TO GET SCOLDED FROM YOU.

Comment: Happy to have helped ;-) Sorry if I was too scolding ;-)

Comment: I created an answer below that should resolve all the problems you encountered initially. Please be so kind and review/accept it if you deem it appropriate, so other users with the same problem won't have to get scolded by me ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ubuntu repositories do not contain the most recent versions. You can use `pip` to install the latest versions.

If you don't have pip installed, use `sudo apt-get install pip` to install it.

Then use

```
sudo pip install --upgrade matplotlib
```

to upgrade matplotlib to the most recent version.

In case, you get an error message like

```
Running setup.py egg_info for package matplotlib
The required version of distribute (>=0.6.28) is not available, and can't be installed while this script is running. Please install a more recent version first, using 'easy_install -U distribute'
```

execute

```
easy_install -U distribute
```

and try `sudo pip install --upgrade matplotlib` again.