# I use "sudo pip uninstall matplotlib" to install matplotlib, but failed

Tags: python, matplotlib, installation

I am using the below setup:

centos 7

python 2.7

numpy 1.14.3

The error information:

```
Cannot uninstall 'matplotlib'.
```

It is a `distutils` installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.

I do not know why I can not use pip to install matplotlib. Somebody knows why?
Do not tell me to use apt-get or yum.

Answer (score 0):

I want to uninstall matplotlib cause its version is too low and I can not upgrade it successfully. So I want to uninstall it, then reinstall. Now I find another way: delete the correspoding file then reinstall the package you need. The version of the package is the latest.

Answer (score 0):

Try  `sudo pip install --upgrade matplotlib` without deleting the old version beforehand, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22106417/6060083)