# Python ImportError: no module named os

Tags: python, pip, sudo, importerror, easy-install

Trying to upgrade matplotlib as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18064159/cant-upgrade-matplotlib), I ran

```
export PYTHONHOME=/usr/lib/python2.7/
sudo easy_install -U distribute
sudo pip install --upgrade matplotlib
```

Now whenever I try to run `python` I get `ImportError: no module named os`. What happened? Please help me. I'm on OS X 10.9.5.

Comment: There are a couple of things to note here:
a) `distribute` was discontinued in favor of `setuptools`
b)  `getpip.py` is the preferred way to bootstrap `setuptools` and `pip`.
c)  I would not recommend setting `PYTHONHOME`, but using `</full/path/to/python/interpreter> -m pip install --upgrade matplotlib`
d) installing directly into system's site-packages directory is usually avoided by using `virtualenv`'s.
That said: Can you give us some hints which OS you are currently working on?

Comment: What are you trying to do here? If you want to upgrade the 2.7 version of a library, just type `sudo pip2 install --upgrade matplotlib` - do not mess with environment variables.

Comment: @cel thank you for the informative explanation. I'm on OS X 10.9.5.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid thank you, but how can I know fix this mess?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was changing `PYTHONHOME`, which could not find any modules because I have python running out of a user directory `/Users/alavin89/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages`. Check the python path by running `echo $PYTHONPATH`.
The fix:

```
unset PYTHONHOME
sudo pip uninstall matplotlib
pip uninstall matplotlib
pip install --user matplotlib
```

Note: running uninstall again w/o `sudo` is to double-check it worked properly.

Comment: Glad you could solve this issue. I would recommend looking into `virtualenv` or `anaconda` and get familiar with the concept of python environments. While these might seem to be a lot of overhead at first sight, you probably will love the concept very soon.

Answer (score -1):

Use Anaconda.

https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/

It has every Python package you could possibly think of - including matplotlib - it updates them all at once as well.

Comment: This is not very good advice. While I use anaconda myself, it is misleading to say that they have `every` python package. Their focus is on scientific packages...

Comment: It is how I solved my problems when my matplotlib was not working correctly. Looks like alavin89 gave a good answer, though.