# ImportError when running terminal command in python

Tags: python, terminal

There is this terminal command in which if I run `someCommand my_file.txt`, it works correctly..

When I tried to incorporate it into a python script as follows:

```
import os
os.system('someCommand /user_data/some_file.txt')
```

I was prompted with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/server/scripts/someCommand", line 6, in <module>
    import os
ImportError: No module named os
```

Tried using `subprocess` but same error persists. How can I rectify this and why is it that `os` module error occurs?
In my python file, `os` is working for sure..

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28534506/python-importerror-no-module-named-os

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling an external command in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python)

Comment: @Antimony - user doesn't set `PYTHONHOME` - how is that a duplicate?

Comment: @Torxed - I don't see how that solves the problem. `os` should be there.

Comment: @tdelaney But perhaps they did that a while back and forgot about it? I added that link as a suggestion that they try whatever has been proposed there.

Comment: What is in the `someCommand` script (that's the one producing the error).

Comment: @PaulRooney that `someCommand` was a terminal command written and put there in place by someone in my company (quite) some time ago. I was trying to use the iteration in my python script and combine it with this `someCommand`

Comment: @Antimony - it would certainly be worth finding out if the example is the whole script. dissidia - is this exactly the script you ran?

Comment: ...and did you run this script from the command line like the example that worked?

Comment: @tdelaney Yes, when running `someCommand my_file.txt` purely in the terminal, it works. The import error occurs only happens when I inserted this command into my python script

Comment: But is the 2 line example you posted your script? This should work and we are trying to figure out where things went wrong. Things like setting `PYTHONPATH` and `PYTHONHOME` or even running from a python virtual env can be problematic.

Comment: Maybe it got to do with my python, I will try to check with someone in my company.. Even so, getting an importError about the os is weird...